# How do I prevent fetch error when adding additional API methods?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-webapi, swagger-ui, visual-studio-2022

I'm building a set of methods in a C# ASP.NET Core Web API with Swagger UI and started with a Login API method which worked fine. I then added another `GetCategoryData` method, which also worked fine. When I added a third `GetCurrentSearch` method, now I get the following error:

[image]

The methods are using Jwt token authentication and work fine on their own. If I comment out `GetCategoryData`, it works fine, the same happens if I comment out `GetCurrentSearch`, but if both are not commented out then I get the above error.

```
    [HttpPost]     //(Name = "Login")]
    public string Login(string username, string pwd)
    {
        // .
        // . 
    }

    [HttpGet]      //(Name = "GetCategoryData")]
    [Authorize(AuthenticationSchemes = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme, Roles = "Administrator")]
    public IEnumerable<CategoryDataModel> GetCategoryData()
    {
        List<CategoryDataModel> prodData = AdminProductResearchController.LoadProductSearch();

        return prodData;
    }

    [HttpGet]     //(Name ="GetCurrentSearch")]
    [Authorize(AuthenticationSchemes = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme, Roles = "Administrator")]
    public IEnumerable<CurrentSearchDataModel> GetCurrentSearch()
    {
        List<CurrentSearchDataModel> currSearchData = AdminCurrentSearchesController.BuildData();

        return currSearchData;
    }
```

What am I missing that prevents me from running all the API's methods together, as I have more to add and can't continue with commenting them out as I go?

Comment: Are you using controllers? Where is your routing? Also since this is a 500 error (internal error) I would be looking for the actual error messages on the internal side, not just the 500 result.

Comment: Yes, this is my API Controller, just under the namespace I have  [ApiController]
 [Route("[controller]")]

Comment: Okay. I haven't thought about this in a little bit. I guess the next question is what do you have in your program startup (probably your `Program.cs` these days)? You want to make sure you are getting your routes mapped (there's two basic choices - conventional routing or attribute routing).  See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/controllers/routing

Comment: Note from these docs: "Placing a route on the controller or action makes it attribute-routed.". So you may be in need of specifying routes for your Gets - it prolly works for only one because its the only `GET` (no ambiguity - router says just use it thanks) but if you have two gets that's another story. OR ... switch to using conventional routing just make sure you set it up correctly.

Comment: @user616076 you can probably test with topsail is saying quick simply by changing one of those `[HttpGet]` to something else like `[HttpPut]` and seeing if the 500 is resolved.  I also wonder if your debug console has any logs in it around this.

Answer (score 1):

In ASP.NET Core API, when add new action method and configure route, we need to make sure that **each method has a unique route or route template**, as ASP.NET Core uses routing to determine which method to invoke based on the incoming HTTP request.

Using your code, after adding the GetCategoryData and GetCurrentSearch action method in the same controller, since both of them using the `[HttpGet]` attribute without adding the additional attribute route, their request paths are both `https://localhost:<port>/api/<Controller>`

To solve this issue, you can put them (two HttpGet method) in different controller or set the different attribute route, like this:

```
[Route("api/[controller]")]
[ApiController]
public class TodoController : ControllerBase
{
    [HttpPost("/Login")]     //(Name = "Login")]
    public string Login(string username, string pwd)
    {
        // .
        // . 
        return "Success";
    }

    //Get /GetCategoryData
    [HttpGet("/GetCategoryData")]      //(Name = "GetCategoryData")]
    [Authorize(AuthenticationSchemes = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme, Roles = "Administrator")]
    public IEnumerable<CategoryDataModel> GetCategoryData()
    {
        List<CategoryDataModel> prodData = new List<CategoryDataModel>();
        prodData.Add(new CategoryDataModel() { ID=1001, Name="A" });
        return prodData;
    }
    //Get api/<Controller>/GetCurrentSearch
    [HttpGet("GetCurrentSearch")]     //(Name ="GetCurrentSearch")]
    [Authorize(AuthenticationSchemes = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme, Roles = "Administrator")]
    public IEnumerable<CurrentSearchDataModel> GetCurrentSearch()
    {
        List<CurrentSearchDataModel> currSearchData = new List<CurrentSearchDataModel>()
        {
            new CurrentSearchDataModel(){ ID=1001, Name="A" },
            };
        return currSearchData;
    }
```

The output as below:

[image]

More detail information, see [Routing to controller actions in ASP.NET Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/controllers/routing?view=aspnetcore-8.0)